# how to add data in my custom theme from WP-Admin Panel

Tags: attachments

anybody who help me to resolve my problem.
suppose i have 1 to 8 **array data** which contain **(image, heading, description)** those i want to display to my page. 
i want these data enter from WP admin panel and display on my custom theme 
i want **function code** for get and display data on **custom theme**.
[image]

Comment: Do you know what files in your theme to edit and how to write PHP code?

Comment: yes 
i know little bit
i want to make widget in functions.php file

Comment: If you already have an array with the data and you know where to write the code to achieve this then what exactly is your question? We're not literally going to write all your code for you

Comment: you can create custom post type using function please follow this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types